Why are these flax leaves turning brown?
Around 3 weeks ago, I sowed some flax seeds (Linum usitatissimum) in a pot of soil. However, some leaves on the seedlings are starting to turn brown and shrivel, especially the lower leaves.


What could be the problem? This is hopefully not some kind of contagious plant disease. The plant is in a hot and humid lowland tropical climate (USDA hardiness zone 13b) near the equator.

Could be nitrogen deficiency. Is it a soilless media?

@Jayparth The pot is filled with topsoil. Could the issue be caused by too much direct sunlight?

nope. In fact flax prefer direct sunlight and is seemingly getting plenty of it. What the signs are showing is mobile nutrient deficiency (nutrients like Nitrogen, Potassium or Phosphorus) or in rare cases if you're overwatering a fungal infection. You can fix mobile nutrient deficiency by a balanced NPK fertilizer or if it's fungal disease, I'll suggest you to go for mancozeb+carbendazim mix available.

Temperature is going to be a major factor in the development of your seedlings. Flax is a crop of temperate climates and is sown very early in the spring cool season, after which it grows fast and vertical straight up to several feet, allowing it to come to flower and seed just as the weather gets warm. Heat will give it a short life. Please take this into account before resorting to chemical treatments which may not be necessary.
